# Iterate a Python list and filter the elements based on another list

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, iteration

I have two lists. The first list has all the names.

```
firstList = ["mike", "mary", "steve", "jane"]
```

The second list contains the name I want to filter.

```
filteredList = ["mike", "mary"]
```

I want to exclude all names in the filtered list so that the final list looks like this:

```
finalList = ["steve","jane"]
```

The names are examples and the number of entries will vary and needs to be dynamic.

I started with this but it didn't run:

```
for b in firstList:
    for s in filteredList:
        finalList = firstList[firstList[b != s]]
        print(finalList)
```

Thoughts? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you have `firstList = ["mike", "mary", "steve", "jane", "jane"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html)

```
#import numpy as np
np.setdiff1d(firstList, filteredList).tolist()
```

or `set` with `-` operator

```
list(set(firstList) - set(filteredList))
```

or [`filter`](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#filter)

```
list(filter(lambda x: x not in filteredList, firstList))
```

**Output**

```
['steve', 'jane']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *list comprehension* to achieve this:

```
firstList = ["mike", "mary", "steve", "jane"]
filteredList = ["mike", "mary"]

finalList = [name for name in firstList if name not in filteredList]
# where `finalList` will hold: ['steve', 'jane']
```

Here you are iterating the `firstList` and checking the presence of each item in `filteredList`. If not present, consider it for your new list.

You can also use [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to achieve this as:

```
set(firstList) - set(filteredList)
# returns: set(['steve', 'jane'])

# if it is must for you to obtain the "finalList" as `list`, 
# you can type-cast it as:
#     finalList = list(set(firstList) - set(filteredList))
```

But via using set, you won't be able to preserve the order of these names in the `firstList`. And it will hold only unique items i.e. repetitive items will be removed. For example: if your "firstList" will contain `["mike", "mike", "mary", "steve", "jane"]`, `finalList` will just contain single `"mike"` whereas in the *list comprehension* based solution I proposed above, you'll see `"mike"` twice.

---

In the code you shared, it could be fixed as:

```
finalList = []

for b in firstList:
    if b not in filteredList: # checking the presence of "b" in "filteredList"
        finalList.append(b)

# where `finalList` will contain: ['steve', 'jane']
```